# Where are music files downloaded from the Google Play Store stored on an Android device?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading, files, google-play-music

I am wondering how music files, downloaded from the Google Play Store, are stored on an Android device.

In other forums on this site, I found that they are located in the `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music` directory. However, I am wondering how the files are named, or organized.

Are they named based on the song name, so for example, would the song "Style" be named under "style.mp3"? Also, are the files organized in a certain file based on a playlist, etc?

Comment: I suppose by music files organized in Google Music you meant the music files downloaded from Play Store. Right?

Comment: Yay for DRM, if you do find them, I would expect them to be encrypted, and disorganized.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to music files downloaded from the Play Store. Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading something you have physically purchased from the Play Store, it should be under `/sdcard/Music` in MP3 files, unless Google has changed their policy recently.

If you have downloaded it with All Access, then it is not available for you to copy. It would be saved in the app's data encrypted, so it would be completely useless to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set in the settings of Google Play Music, if you have set to cache on the external SD card, your songs can be found in,
`/external_sd/Android/data/com.google.android.music/files/music/`

If you have used the internal storage or do not have any sd card inserted the songs can be found in `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/files/music`